# Поиск минимального ненулевого элемента массива

Tags: c++, stl

Есть массив `std::vector<unsigned int> mas`, нужно найти минимальный среди ненулевых элементов.

Просто минимальный легко находится таким способом:

```
auto min_pos = std::min_element (mas.begin (), mas.end (), [&](unsigned int a, unsigned int b){ return a < b; });
unsigned int m = *min_pos;
```

Я специально написал с лямбдой, потому что (мне кажется) нужно что-то хитрое в неё добавить, что именно - что-то не могу сообразить.

Модифицировать массив нельзя, если бы было можно - я бы сделал ему `std::remove` и далее по накатанной.

Comment: `{ return (a-1) < (b-1); }` работает?

Comment: для unsigned int да, очень красивый способ ) в принципе это вопрос закрывает, но хотелось бы более масштабируемый вариант, чтобы работало и для int ...

Comment: Если результаты привести к (unsigned int) `{ return ((unsigned int)(a-1) < (unsigned int)(b-1)); }` то и для int должно подойти, если там есть вообще положительные

Comment: *"Просто минимальный легко находится таким способом"* - этот код вообще не работает, так как производит доступ в массиве по индексу со значением минимального элемента, кроме того, за счет неявного преобразования беззнакового `int` в знаковый 0xFF000000 будет считаться меньше 1.

Comment: Исправил. Ошибки потянулись, так как это кусок кода из большой программы, пытался упростить, оставив суть, и в итоге ошибся -_- ...

Comment: *"специально написал с лямбдой"* - затруднительно придумать этому хоть какое-то обоснование. ¿Чем не угодил простой цикл по всем элементам? Там еще кстати можно было бы сделать быстрый выход при нахождении 1.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Сильное заявление, учитывая, что вы написали ответ, котором аж 5 сравнений в лямбде. Кроме того, наличие единичного элемента представляется вполне распространенным кандидатом для оптимизации, а если оно таковым не является, то проверку тривиально отключить без переделывания остального алгоритма.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Придумывать на ходу такие сомнительные придирки - дело неблагодарное. Вот вы начали противоречить сами себе. ¿Оптимизация пяти сравнений по-вашему - дело компилятора, а оптимизация одного опционального сравнения для быстрого выхода - не дело компилятора? Еще одно сильное заявление однако... ¿А то, что у вас остается якобы аж три сравнения, вас не смущает? Ну и также давно известно, что проверки для быстрого выхода - эффективная оптимизация. А если 1 встречается все-таки редко, то проверку легко убрать, не затрагивая остальной алгоритм.

Comment: А что должно быть на выходе, если все элементы нулевые?

Comment: `mas.end ()` подойдёт

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Буду предельно краток :), вот она, лямбда:

```
[&](int a, int b){ return a && (!b || a < b); }
```

Comment: `[&]` -> `[]`. Иначе краткость не предельная.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Я всего лишь имел в виду, что ограничусь лямбдой и не буду приводить весь текст...

Answer (score 0):

Придумал такой вариант

```
auto min_pos = std::min_element (mas.begin (), mas.end (), [&](int a, int b){ return a != 0 && a < b; });
if (min_pos != mas.end ())
    std::cout << "минимум = " << mas[*min_pos] << std::endl;
else
    std::cout << "нету ненулевых элементов" << std::endl;
```

Но, возможно, есть более правильный способ?

Comment: Если множество заведомо непустое, то как может отсутствовать минимальный элемент?... Или вам надо отрабатывать и пустое множество? Но тогда возврат 1 — решение по сути неверное.

Comment: исправил, добавил обработку отсутствия минимума

Comment: Проверьте свое решение на, скажем, `{0,1,2}`. А заодно и моё :) — `[&](int a, int b){ return a && (!b || a < b); }` См. https://ideone.com/UZYUJE

Comment: Спасибо, моё не работает, если первым идёт 0, а ваше работает. Напишите как ответ, поставлю плюсиков :) .

Comment: А тут все те же проблемы, что и в коде из вопроса.

Comment: Решение не отвечает требованиям [strict weak ordering](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare).

Answer (score 0):

Зададим полный порядок, в котором нулевые значения больше любых других:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a = {0, 1, 2};
    auto min_pos = std::min_element(a.begin(), a.end(), [](auto a, auto b){
        // nonzero < zero
        if ((a != 0) && (b == 0)) {
            return true;
        }
        // !(zero < nonzero)
        if ((a == 0) && (b != 0)) {
            return false;
        }
        // zero    < zero    OR
        // nonzero < nonzero
        return a < b;
    });
    std::cout << *min_pos << '\n';
}
```

Лямбда рефакторится до вида, который [Harry](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/195342/harry) уже привел в [комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1549585/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0/1549591#comment2789904_1549587) и [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1549593/416121):

```
    auto min_pos = std::min_element(a.begin(), a.end(), [](auto a, auto b){
        return (a != 0) && ((b == 0) || (a < b));
    });
```